# Wordpress & jQuery - import <?php bloginfo('url'); ?> to script file

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress and I would like to use the value of `<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>` in a jQuery script file as a variable. Is that possible? And how?

In my script.js file I a function that uses:

```
$("#board").load("http://www.mysite.com/ajax/",{slug:post_slug});
```

and the "http://www.mysite.com" part will change (I'm building a theme).

Many thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're asking for is not easily achieved, instead set a JavaScript variable in your `<head>` element:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var site_url = '<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>';
</script>
```

Then you can use the `site_url` variable in any of your JS files:

```
alert(site_url);
```

**August 2020 update**

You should check out WordPress' [wp_localize_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/) function instead, this allows you to specify additional data to be made available to a queued script.

Here's a good example by [mikeschinkel on Github](https://gist.github.com/mikeschinkel/5d43b23110fa23f733e01e02fb521755).

Comment: This answers the question ;-) but using a relative path works also.

Comment: Indeed, using relative paths is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

```
var bloginfo_url = "<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>";
$("#board").load(bloginfo_url + "/ajax/", {slug:post_slug});
```

But why can't you use relative URLs?

```
$("#board").load("/ajax/", {slug:post_slug});
```

Comment: He's got that code in a external `.js` file, so the PHP most likely won't be parsed (unless he's configured his web server).

Comment: @Matt: Ah, all right. My point point with relative URLs remains valid, though.

Comment: Oh! lol it works using $("#board").load("ajax/", {slug:post_slug}); I thought it didn't work during my test, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `http://my-site.com/ajax`, I would recommend using `admin_url('admin-ajax.php')` which is a standard entry point for handling ajax calls in WP.
Also, there is [wp_localize_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) function that will help you declaring JS variable.

Comment: OK... Do you know where I could find examples about using these when I want to load posts like I am ?

Comment: Hmm, `wp_localize_script` is pretty straightforward thing with examples available in Codex (I linked to it).

Comment: wp_localize_script to declare variables ok but what about using admin-ajax.php ? Where can I find a howto ?

Comment: Read the code, Luke :) It is not documented as far as I know. But it is pretty straightforward - you call that file with Ajax request and `action` GET parameter which is "translated" into WordPress action execution, so for example `/wp-admin/wp-ajax.php?action=my_action` will call the action `wp_ajax_my_action` or `wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action` depending on if you are logged in.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you'll have to run you Javascript file through PHP and use  instead of "http://www.mysite.com/ajax/".

You can also try to use window.location which is a Javascript property.